# How to run custom code at login with flask-security

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I am new to flask, but moderately proficient in python - I have a flask app that uses flask-security for user authentication.  I would like to add some additional functionality to the user login process.  Specifically, I need to save the user's auth_token (which I have set up to be a one-time-use token) to the db when they login, and remove it when they log out.  The issue comes because flask-security does not (to my knowledge) expose the machinery of logging in directly to the developer.  As far as I can tell from the code, it imports flask-login, which uses a login_user function.

I started out by trying to override this function by importing flask.ext.login (which normally, I would not need to do) and redefining the function as follows:

```
import flask.ext.login as a
def new_login_user():
    ...copy of existing function goes here...
    ...Plus new stuff with current_user.get_auth_token()...
a.login_user = new_login_user
```

however, I got hit with all sorts of namespace issues, and it seems like a really ugly way to do it.

I was thinking there might be a way to do it with a decorator, but I am new to flask, and have not used decorators much regardless.

Any ideas on what the best way to approach this might be?  for context, I want the auth_token in the db, because I need to pass off the website authentication to another process, which also accesses the db.  The other process is an API server using websockets.  I don't want to combine the processes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think using a signal decorator seems to be the easiest-- in the following example `on_user_logged_in` should be called when a user logs into your app.  More info [in the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/signals/#decorator-based-signal-subscriptions).

```
from flask.ext.login import user_logged_in

@user_logged_in.connect_via(app)
def on_user_logged_in(sender, user):
    log_auth_token(user.get_auth_token()) # or whatever.
```

Comment: worked a treat, this is still an idiom I am getting comfortable with.  In my other Python projects I have never used decorators, but Flask is full of them...  A Note, the @user_logged_in docs are not at the link you provided, those point to the general decorator based signal subscription docs for flask as a whole.  They were helpful, but the ones for flask-login are [here](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#signals). (I leave them behind for others to enjoy!)  Thanks Doobeh!

Answer (score 0):

Best keep it clean, write your own `new_login_user` function and use that whenever you would otherwise use `flask.ext.login.login_user`. You could put your `new_login_user` into its own file and import it from there.

You could even call it `login_user`, and never import `flask.ext.login.login_user` directly.

Comment: thing is, I never import/use login_user directly, the flask-security module imports flask-login, which, in turn, uses it.  I don't think I can import around it, and still get all the other functionality. Hope that is clearer..