# How to override login of flask-security?

Tags: flask-security

I want to do some customization when a user logs in. The problem is that the project is using flask-security which implicitly handles user login.
I want to check some records of users in the database when users log in.

How can I override "login" function in flask-security?

I saw a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114445/how-to-run-custom-code-at-login-with-flask-security), and tried it but it's not working.
Plus,  it is not exactly what I want to do.
I maybe need to stop the default behavior in case of some users.

So, is anyone having this kind of issue? How can I do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can override the login form when you are setting up Flask-Security:

```
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore, login_form=CustomLoginForm)
```

Then create your custom login form class that extends the default LoginForm. And override the validate function to do stuff before or after the login attempt.

```
from flask_security.forms import LoginForm

class CustomLoginForm(LoginForm):
    def validate(self):
        # Put code here if you want to do stuff before login attempt

        response = super(CustomLoginForm, self).validate()

        # Put code here if you want to do stuff after login attempt

        return response
```

"reponse" will be True or False based on if the login was successful or not. If you want to check possible errors that occurred during the login attempt see "self.errors"

Greetings,
Kevin ;)

Comment: so basically if you write a /login route if you use Flask-Security - the route you write is never used :/

Comment: @VaidøtasI. I am fairly sure it is not used indeed

Answer (score 3):

after registering the flask security extension, you can create an endpoint with the exact same name/route and it should override the one registered by Flask-security.

If you are using blueprints, make sure you register your blueprint before registering Flask-security.

Comment: The concept here works but when using Blueprints you must register your blueprint BEFORE registering Flask-security.  Which ever function is decorated as the route and registered first wins. as of 0.3.2.  Flask-Security will fill in if not provided.  You also must set the Config setting `SECURITY_LOGIN_URL` to match otherwise you will have 2 routes for auth.

Comment: That's correct. I have updated my answer. thanks

Comment: I've been trying to do just that, but the user_datastore doesn't recognize my tables. I make sure to import my models. I register the blueprint first, and the route is found. I set up the user_datastore and security last. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, you can disable the default flask-security blueprint during the Security object init `app.security = Security(app, user_datastore, register_blueprint=False)`.